# Java tile based map from array positioning

Tags: java, dictionary, tile

I don"t understand why my code is producing what is shown below. I want the tiles to be aligned in the window. The window size is set in the main class:

```
this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y));
```

This is my class for the map.

```
public class Map1 {

int mapx = 19;
int mapy = 19;

int tileWidth = 600 / (mapx + 1);
int tileHeight = 500 / (mapy + 1);

int[][] map =      {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

public void drawLevel(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    for (int x = 0; x <= mapx; x++){

        for (int y = 0; y <= mapy; y++){

            int L = x * tileWidth;
            int U = y * tileHeight;
            int R =  tileWidth;
            int D =  tileHeight;

            if (map[y][x] == 1){
                //g.fillRect((x * tileWidth), (y * tileHeight), (x + tileWidth), (y + tileHeight));
                g.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
            }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

http://www.flickr.com/photos/88246499@N05/8067438151/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nested for loop in `drawLevel` you use the variable `y` to index the x coordinate of your tile map, and `x` to index the y coordinate. The problem arises when you define `L` and `U` because you are multiplying with the wrong dimension of the tile. Because inside your loops `x` is a measure along the height you have to write `int U = x*tileHeight;` and `int L = y*tileWidth`.

I swapped the two for loops in the following code, so `x` and `y` have the common meaning.

```
for (int y = 0; y <= mapy; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x <= mapx; x++){
        int L = x * tileWidth;
        int U = y * tileHeight;
        int R =  tileWidth;
        int D =  tileHeight;
        if (map[x][y] == 1){
            g.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense, however the tiles are being drawn behind the border instead of the top left corner of the visible screen.